# Создание ЧПУ типа: site.com/policy/domestic/{date}{id}.html

Tags: php, чпу

В сети полно инструкций для создания ЧПУ-ссылок. Но во всех создаются простые сслыки типа `site.com/{post_id}.html`. А мне нужно создать ссылку в виде `site.com/policy/domestic/{date}{id}.html`. При чем `policy` должно преобразоваться в ID категории (например: `cat_id=1`). Какими способами можно реализовать это? Конечно, можно для каждой категории создать правило. Но это неудобно.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать фромат `site.com/{cat}/domestic/{date}{id}.html`? А уже потом в одном разбирать плейсхолдеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, вопрос не совсем корректен. Но, судя по всему вы пишите на голом php, я бы вам предложил создать .htaccess, примерно такого содержания:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/domestic/(\d{4})(.*).html$ index.php?cat_name=$1&date=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

В результате, если вы выведете массив $_GET в index.php, вы увидите, что в нем содержатся переменные cat_name=policy, date=4 цифры(я не знаю в каком формате у вас дата) и id.

> При чем policy должно преобразоваться в ID категории (например: cat_id=1)

Дальше вам останится по cat_name найти cat_id - так, как где-то должны у вас хранится соответствия cat_id=1=policy.

Comment: Да, пишу на голом php. Вместо domestic может быть и  другая подкатегория, например, foreign. У меня 25 категорий и подкатегорий. И неизвестно, какую еще категорию добавят. Создавать правило для каждого - это неудобно. Может отдельной функцией можно сделать как-то?

Comment: 1. Зачем создавать для каждой категории? 2. Если не рассматривать ЧПУ, как бы вы записали этот url используя GET параметры? P.S. По сути вам требуется подогнать этот GET, под мой пример. А правил в htaccess будет столько, сколько видов страниц на сайте(страница каталога, страница продуктов, текстовая страница и т.д.). Также можно написать регулярку для бесконечного количества уровней (чтобы получилось policy/domestic = $_GET['categories'])- только потом придется на стороне php разбирать количество уровней и узнавать текущий.

Comment: У меня есть: -страница новостей по категориям - `site.com\view=category&cat_id=2`, страница поиска - `site.com\view=search&query=some-text`, страница вывода новости - `site.com\view=single&cat_id=2&sub_cat_id=12&post_id=234`, страница вывода новостей по дате - `site.com\view=archive&date=2015-08-16`. В принципе, я знаю как это сделать. Для архива, поиска и категорий легко сделать. задал правило и все. Мне нужно только перевести название категории в ИД. Вопрос в том как это реализовать.

Comment: У вас категории хранятся в БД, то для каждой категории создается еще поле name, в котором хранится его ЧПУ, например = policy или domestic. А вы потом делаете запрос в БД для поиска текущего раздела не по id, а по полю name. И линки ЧПУ вы же тоже должны как-то создавать.

Comment: Думаю, это самый приемлимый вариант.

Answer (score 1):

ЧПУ предназначено для преобразования ссылок, но оно не может заменить логику вашей CMS, если CMS в качестве категории ожидает получить ID, а вы пытаетесь передать ей название.
Обычно в таких ситуациях передают именно название категории, а уже в CMS делают поиск по названию и получают её ID для дальнейших действий.

Конечно, можно быть мазохистом и прописывать для каждой категории свой ID, но это очень плохое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы дать точный ответ на ваш вопрос нужно понять - а что вы используте? Если CMS, то какую? А если собственное решение, то на базе какого фреймворка?

По той информации, что известна сейчас могу только подсказать, что механизм, когда policy преобразуется в ID - очень популярен, policy в этом случае называется "slug".

Comment: Пишу на голом PHP. Как можно реализовать это?

Comment: Действительно проще использовать готовый фреймворк, чем самостоятельно реализовывать парсинг URL. Достаточно взглянуть на то, как парсинг ЧПУ реализуется в Yii2, чтобы понять - самому до этого дойти можно, но набив кучу шишек. Как я понял по вашему профилю - вы не велосипед хотите изобретать а создать сайт, как можно быстрее и проще. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlRule.php

Comment: Я только начинаю заниматься разработкой сайтов и хочу изучить пути создания ЧПУ. А так, конечно же готовые фреймворки проще использовать. Спасибо за совет.